# Android Studio don't know where is Java

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-studio

I am getting this error:

> Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386/bin/java" (in directory "/home/sergiy/.AndroidStudioPreview/system/compile-server"): error=2, No such file or directory

This happens after i remove all JDK (Open and other). Some time before I installed Oracle JDK from official site. So, new folder of JDK named jdk1.7.0.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0

JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0

java version "1.7.0_21"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

Android studio starts without any errors. I think that a must rename path to JDK in Android studio? But how?

Comment: Did you move *any* of the files? When I started off, I was getting a similar error (except mine was for a different file). I figured out it was because I had moved one of my files thinking that the Android SDK would automatically update the file path, but that was not the case. When I moved the files back to the original location it fixed the error and I think that's what happened to you too.

Comment: No, I don't not move any files. The first try was to rename folder to java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386 that android studio wants. I changed JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME, but after all of this manipulation java was missing.

Comment: Ok. I probably misunderstood your questions. Glad that you got if fixed though. Also, if you solved your problem, you should go ahead and add it as an answer below when it gives you the option do so.

Comment: I tryed, but my raiting was to low so I must wait 8 hours to do it. I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: Yup. I just wanted to remind you. Cheers!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

All done! I find it in File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure->SDKs. There I change JDK home path.

Comment: Hi, perhaps you can help me out. I can't find that setting in the latest version of Android Studio (v 3.0) and I'm getting EXACTLY the same error as you were. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, I have no Linux and android studio now.

Comment: I had the same problem but my solution was to use a direct path instead of a link. Doesn't seem to work in Android Studio 0.9.0 to use links for some reason.

Comment: Had to erase the local.properties file and restart Android Studio after doing this to fix

Comment: Android Studio > Preferences? Naw, that's way too obvious. We're gonna tuck it down here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Took me 2 days and at least 1000 Google searches to find this one answer, which solved my problem, that java jdk returns unknown error.

Answer (score 4):

For Android Studio 1.5 (and hopefully later versions)

1. Go to Top Menu **File** and select **Project Structure**
2. Select the **SDK location** option on the left
   and enter the path of you JDK in the **JDK location**

[image: Android Studio SDK JDK location]

Comment: I accept with the new location selected, but if I come back to this window, the location is still for jdk 1.7 instead of 1.8. ```Accept``` or ```Apply``` don't show errors, but don't apply the changes.

Comment: @JCarlos I dont know if that can be caused by permission issues

Comment: I can't save the changes from the Project Structure window. I was looking for a file with the jdk path, and finally solved this problem editing this XML file: ```.AndroidStudio2.1\config\options```. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work for AndroidStudio 3.1.2.  @halfer's solution worked for me.