# Android studio 1.1 - change JRE used for running studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

I have Android Studio 1.1 on a Windows 8.1 machine.

There are several JDKs installed on my machine (1.6, 1.7, 1.8) and Android studio uses 1.8 (I can see that in the about popup).

I want to change the JVM used for running Android Studio to 1.7, since I have some performance problems and I suspect it has to do something with using JRE 1.8.

What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: Here it is:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823790/android-studio-dont-know-where-is-java/16824891#16824891

Comment: This is the problem..  File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure->SDKs show 1.7, but the about screen shows 1.8

Comment: @Ran What do you mean the "about" screen shows 1.8? Also, do you want the the apps to be compiled with 1.7 as well?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Help->About

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer here solves your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27999642/4114992

In particular, the start script states:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.
# Try (in order): STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, "java" in PATH
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, if you set `STUDIO_JDK` as an environment variable, to, say, 1.7, you should be able to override the JRE used by Android Studio itself.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried navigating to File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Compiler (expand) -> Java Compiler and changing "Project bytecode version (leave blank for jdk default):" to 1.7?

This on top of Mismanc's comment about File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure -> SDK Location and changing "JDK Location:" to path to "C:(pathname)\Java\jdk1.7.X_XX" should change what you're looking for.

Comment: He's asking how to change the JRE which runs Android Studio - not the JDK used by the project in Android Studio.

Comment: Misunderstood what the question was asking, though I still don't see how Mismanc's comment wasn't satisfactory.

Comment: I think Mismanc's comment points to a link which tells you how to set the default JDK used for new projects (which is not what the question is asking) - but I could be wrong.