# All java methods are not working properly in android studio how to resolve it?

Tags: java, android

[image]

how to fix the problem of java development tool kit path?

Comment: did you read what it says in that popup SETUP JDK

Comment: yes, but my JDK is already set @VivekMishra

Comment: show the screenshot of your jdk path

Comment: as it showing....setup your JDK...

Comment: Point `Android Studio` to the place where you JDK resides. That should clear it up.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823790/android-studio-dont-know-where-is-java

Answer (score 0):

File > Project Structure > Project

Then point the SDK to JDK (Default is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JDK" for 32 bit.

Hope this helps!

Edit: File>Other Settings>Default Project Structure>SDKs for android studio